# How to separate characters, numbers and symbols in Java?

Tags: java

I have a problem, I have some strings, like this

```
تاپقان بولۇپ، توپلامغا 1998 – يىلىدىن 2009يىلىغىچە شىنجاڭ
```

Yes, they are written in Uyghur, much like Arabic, and I don't know Uyghur.

I need to separate them by spaces, symbols, and numbers now.
I tried it with python and I can get this result.

```
تاپقان   بولۇپ ،    توپلامغا      1998       –    يىلىدىن      2009   يىلىغىچە   شىنجاڭ
```

If I ignore a lot of spaces, the result is what I want.
and the python code is

```
def re_str(matched):
    replace_str = matched.group('symbol')
    return ' ' + replace_str + " "
# test is the string above
print(re.sub('(?P<symbol>\W)', re_str, re.sub('(?P<symbol>\d+)', re_str, test)))
```

The question now is: I want to use Java to achieve this effect, but I don't know how to do it? please help me

I try in Java, but it doesn't work

```
String pattern = "(\\d+)|([\\p{P}\\p{S}]+)|\\W";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(test);
```

Comment: What have you tried in Java? You have some experience with Python, so much of it will be similar. You just have to sort out the syntax and differences with how String replacement works. Basically, no one is going to write this code for you.

Comment: Have a look at Java regular expressions, specifically the classes `Pattern` and `Matcher`. The Javadocs associated with those should contain a lot of info already.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I just learned Java, I don't know how to implement the function like re.sub in python in Java.@jdv

Comment: Thank you, I checked the information, tried to use Patter and Matcher, but it doesn't seem to work.@Thomas

Comment: If latter snippet is your entire Java code, then you're missing the actual splitting of the string part. The method you're looking for is on Pattern class, its full signature is `String[] split(CharSequence)`. There's also a useful `splitAsString` method on there you may wish to look into. Alternatively, you could simply call method `split` of `String` class: it accepts a regular expression as input parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use combination of `isAlphabetic` and `isDigit`, otherwise you have a special character.

```
public class Separater {

static String splitString(String str) {
    String result = "";
    int i=0;
    while (i < str.length()) {//Using while instead of for, to avoid skipping characters due to auto increment by the loop.

        if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) {
            while (i < str.length() && Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) {
                result += str.charAt(i);
                i++;
            }
            result += "     ";
        } else if (Character.isAlphabetic(str.charAt(i))) {
            while (i < str.length() && Character.isAlphabetic(str.charAt(i))) {
                result += str.charAt(i);
                i++;
            }
            result += "     ";
        } else {
            while (i < str.length() && !Character.isAlphabetic(str.charAt(i)) && !Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))) {
                result += str.charAt(i);
                i++;
            }
            result += "     ";
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(splitString("تجاؤي#*(اىيلاؤت678345شسسصي*&&*^*!!محجذلب"));
}
}
```

**Output**
Note that the space between the substring is larger but [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/) removes extra spaces!

> تجاؤي     #*(     اىيلاؤت     678345     شسسصي     *&&*^*!!     محجذلب

Comment: great! it works for me, thank you , I am trapped in a regular expression. :)

Answer (score 0):

I made a function that you should be able to do just that, I'm not sure exactly which symbols you want so you'll have to modify the SYMBOL_MATCHER_REGEX to match any symbols you are looking for.

The $0 is the reference to the match found by the pattern, the function simply replaces the match with itself, but with tabs before and after added.

```
  /**
   * The regex used to find any symbols you are looking for.
   */
  private String SYMBOL_MATCHER_REGEX = "[0-9]+";

  /**
   * A replacement which adds space before and after the match.
   */
  private String REPLACEMENT_STRING = "   $0    ";

  /** 
   * Compiled pattern for the SYMBOL_MATCHER_REGEX. 
   */
  private Pattern SYMBOL_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(SYMBOL_MATCHER_REGEX);

  public String formatUyghur(String uyghurText) {
    Matcher matcher = SYMBOL_PATTERN.matcher(uyghurText);

    return matcher.replaceAll(REPLACEMENT_STRING);
  }
```